# AMQP Connector Socket Connect Error: TimeoutError in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: python, rabbitmq, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks, azure-synapse-analytics

I am trying to access RabbitMQ (hosted in AWS) from Azure Synapse via Python code in Notebooks. Both servers (Azure and AWS) have been configured to access each other like the firewall setup is already completed and I am able to run the same code via Azure VM created in Azure Synapse. But I am unable to access it in Azure Synapse Analytics due to AMQP TimeOut Error. Could you guys help me here?

[image]

I tried to create some Vnetz in Azure Synapse portal and also with Linked Services, it was not working but then I tried to access them via Azure Virtual Machine (created within Azure Synapse Analytics), and it worked. But unable to access it in Azure Synapse. Can someone tell me what could help me to access them in my Azure Synapse Analytics (Notebooks)?